# Creating Berkeley DB database from F#

Tags: f#, berkeley-db

I was trying to create a Berkeley DB database from F#. So I was using libdb_dotnet51.dll ,libdb_csharp51.dll, libdb51.dll .

but the statement -

```
env = DatabaseEnvironment.Open("Datababase_name",new DatabaseEnvironmentconfig())
```

is throwing an unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in libdb_dotnet51.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for 'BerkeleyDB.Internal.libdb_csharpPINVOKE' threw an exception.

I have also added the dll path to the path environment variable!

how to resolve the issue.

Comment: probably x64 vs x86 mismatch when loading the native library